# Is it possible to create my own custom KvExt table to fully implement and manage User Defined Fields for my custom table and page?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom table in SQL Server called AnimalBreed and maintenance page.
I wish to add User Defined Field support via the KvExt approach instead of 
traditional practices involving either CSAnswers or a CacheExtension of the 
DAC and underlying "Usr" fields.

Is this possible?

Can it be done for line-level (child) DACs, such as 
existing INLocation and INLocationKvExt?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

It appears the feature needs at least:

1. ensure your table has the NoteID column as uniqueidentifier datatype and the DAC has the corresponding field: Guid? NoteID and [PXNote()] attribute.
2. In the ASPX, if not ListView, add the following to the PXDataSource tag:
   EnableAttributes="true"

By making these changes, I can Manage User Defined Fields, choose Attributes to include, and I can store values to the KvExt table.

I am using Version = 19.205.0023

Sales Order page observation:  if I add two UDFs on SO Order Entry page, one is combobox and one is checkbox, setting their values saves just fine, but then updating the combobox and save leads to loss of the checkbox (from true to false), unless you uncheck and recheck prior to the save.  Is this a bug?

Comment: I was able to add the UDF feature nicely to my custom table and page. However, if two checkboxes are offered for the user, and a change is made to one of them, the other checkbox will lose its value.  Importantly, if I add the UDF support to an earlier version of Acumatica, the checkboxes hold their values just fine after updating one of them. The success was tested with earlier Acumatica 2018 R2 Build 18.208.0013..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe technically possible but definitely not recommended to use undocumented feature like KvExt.

If you need to deploy User Defined Fields on a page which already contains them. Configure them manually and then add them in a customization package in the user defined fields section for deployment as described here:
https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=e01f29d3-b6b1-40f4-a2d1-45c9d01bdde3

Example:
[image]